# SQL Procedure that will calculate the Last Price paid for a certain Part

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedure

I am trying to write an SQL Procedure that will calculate the Last Price paid for a certain Part.

```
DECLARE @ItemId int;

SET @ItemId = 1;

SELECT
SD.Price
FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS SH
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS SD
ON SH.Id = SD.HeaderId
WHERE (SD.LineItemId = @ItemId)
AND (SH.OrderDate = (SELECT
    MAX(SH.OrderDate) AS Expr1
FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS SH
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS SD
    ON SH.Id = SD.HeaderId
WHERE (SD.LineItemId = @ItemId))
)
```

This does produce the results I wanted but, I am doing everything twice. Would someone point me in a better direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that your subselect is basically the same as your main select, chances are that this subselect is indeed a bit of overkill. Looking at your logic, what you want to achieve is to get the `Price` of the `SalesOrderDetail` linked to the `SalesOrderHeader` with the most recent `OrderDate`, so let's use an `ORDER BY DESC` and select only the first answer.

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SD.Price
FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS SH
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS SD
    ON SH.Id = SD.HeaderId
WHERE SD.LineItemId = @ItemId
ORDER BY SH.OrderDate DESC
```

Comment: That is so simple, I am ashamed I missed it.

Answer (score 3):

@BCdotWEB already provided [a good solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115900/42632), so I will mention some other ways to improve your code.

---

Your formatting makes your query difficult to read. Try using some indentation and advantageously placed line breaks to give it a better visual structure. You also have unnecessary round brackets around each expression in your `WHERE` clauses, which distract from the query logic. Here is how I would format it:

```
DECLARE @ItemId int;

SET @ItemId = 1;

SELECT
    SD.Price
FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS SH
    INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS SD
        ON SH.Id = SD.HeaderId
WHERE SD.LineItemId = @ItemId
AND SH.OrderDate = (
    SELECT
        MAX(SH.OrderDate) AS Expr1
    FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS SH
        INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS SD 
            ON SH.Id = SD.HeaderId
    WHERE SD.LineItemId = @ItemId
);
```

---

You are using the same aliases for your outer and inner queries, which could potentially cause ambiguous queries, and also make the code more difficult to understand. Furthermore, `SH` and `SD` do not make for very good aliases, as they do not say anything about what they refer to. We could rename them to `hdr` and `dtl`, which are only one extra char, but actually give you a visual aid to see what it is referring to.

Now we have a query that reads easier. Note I added the `last` prefix to your inner aliases, and renamed column alias `Expr1` (which is meaningless) to `lastOrderDate`.

```
SELECT
    dtl.Price
FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS hdr
    INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS dtl
        ON hdr.Id = dtl.HeaderId
WHERE dtl.LineItemId = @ItemId
AND hdr.OrderDate = (
    SELECT
        MAX(lastHdr.OrderDate) AS lastOrderDate
    FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS lastHdr
        INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS lastDtl 
            ON lastHdr.Id = lastDtl.HeaderId
    WHERE lastDtl.LineItemId = @ItemId
);
```

Answer (score 3):

pre: this question sound more fitting for "Stack overflow", than "Code Review"

how about (so often 'underused') `group by / having` with `min`/`max` condition?

BCdotWEBs solution is very fine if you have already one @ItemId

if you want the latest prices for many/all @ItemIds then working with group by / having can be very performant, because you only need one query and not one for each @ItemId

I am not sure if I understood your DB design, but the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT SD.LineItemId, SD.Price
    FROM SalesOrderHeaders AS SH
    INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails AS SD
        ON SH.Id = SD.HeaderId
---WHERE SD.LineItemId = @ItemId
    group by 
        SD.LineItemId
    having 
        SH.OrderDate = MAX(SH.OrderDate)
```